# Is there a way to retrieve the "Frequent Locations" stored with iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, location

The iPhone's `Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> System Services -> Frequent Locations`, if turned on, can store quite some very interesting location information about the device. Can a custom App retrieve this information? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The frequent location is managed by the maps application. iOS doesn't have a lot of inter-app communication, and the interface for getting location services is using [Corelocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html), which does not provide this functionality.